# Is Conditional Independence stable under unions regarding the condition?

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditional-probability

I stumbled across the question whether the following implication is true:
Let $A,B,C,D$ be random variables.
$$(A\perp B\mid C)\land (A\perp B \mid D)\Rightarrow (A\perp B\mid (C,D))$$
Intuitively, I'd say that this implication is true, but I failed to show it formally and I can not see how the statement can be derived by the usual properties of conditional independence ([What does the decomposition, weak union and contraction rule mean for conditional probability and what are their proofs?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/855002/what-does-the-decomposition-weak-union-and-contraction-rule-mean-for-conditiona)), even though I suspect that Pearl uses this implication in a proof.
My concern is that on the LHS, one conditions on the $\sigma$-field generated by $C$ or $D$, respectively, but on the RHS one conditions on $\sigma(\sigma(C)\cup\sigma(D))$, which might be bigger than the union of the $\sigma$-fields relevant for the LHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider three independent fair coin-tosses.  Let $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ be the indicator random variables for the events 
$$ \eqalign{ A: & \text{first toss heads}\cr
             B: & \text{second toss heads}\cr
             C: & \text{third toss heads}\cr
             D: & \text{an odd number of heads in the three tosses}\cr}
$$ 
$A$ and $B$ are independent given $C$, and $A$ and $B$ are independent given $D$, but $A + B \equiv C + D \mod 2$ so $A$ and $B$ are not independent given $C$ and $D$.